# How to slide a title horizontally and shift the bottom part by x px?

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmMhh.png) with css so I can have a title `<h1>DISCOVER <span>WEB 3</span> DIMENSIONS</h1>`

How would you do it ?

Thanks,

Tried google, friends who told me to ask chatgpt but not successfull...

Comment: Hi! I created a solution y'day, but forgot to post. Also with `clip-path`, yet a different approach. Here's the link to the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/OJodBBv) with a few range sliders so you can toy with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Css:

```
/* Aligning container in center*/
.container {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 35%;
    left: 35%;
    color: Black;
  
}

/* General styling to text and
transition of 2s*/  
.text {
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 7rem;
}

/* Giving shapes to text using clip-path*/  
.text1 {
    clip-path: inset(56px 0 0 0px);
}

.text2 {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0 73px 0px);
}

/* transforming box 1 position on hover */  
.box .text1 {
    transform: translateX(3px);
}

/* transforming box 2 position on hover */  
.box .text2 {
    transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Create container -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- create div with class box -->
    <div class="box">

        <!-- write the text to be splitted
            into two p tags -->
        <p class="text text1">Web3</p>

        <p class="text text2">Web3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked ! https://codepen.io/sbounmy/pen/ExeMVJv

Answer (score 0):

You might find it a lot easier to get your text as an image, splice it in two horizontally, and slide those two images inside a div with an animation. As far as I am aware there isn't anything I have ever touched in CSS that does what you're asking.

The only work around I can think of is making CSS to write out the letters via animation, and adjusting that animation to offset it when it is below a certain Y axis? That seems like a huge amount of work compared to splicing an image.